# Get remote ip GraphQL express Node

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

Follow this tutorial of GraphQL in NodeJS with express: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/authentication-and-express-middleware/
Seems like  is easy get ip, but when i try in local:

> Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'ip' of undefined
>       at Object.ip (/Users/mac/Documents/repos/rebuspluginapi/src/app.ts:85:20)
>       at /Users/mac/Documents/repos/rebuspluginapi/src/controllers/social-campaings.controller.ts:41:19
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at /Users/mac/Documents/repos/rebuspluginapi/src/controllers/social-campaings.controller.ts:8:71
>       at new Promise ()

The code:

```
let root = {
  ip: function (args, request) {
    return request.ip;
  }
};
// Rutas graphQL
app.use(
  '/v1/graphql',
  cors(),
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: mergeSchemas({ schemas }),
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true
  })
);
```

And error produces when i try to access to IP:

```
console.log(queryParams.ip);
```

Comment: Your request object is undefined somehow

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, what is `queryParams`. Did you have variable of `queryParams`?

But When I tried to tutorial, it isn't problem.

I think the source has changed a little after 8 months.

```
var express = require('express');
var { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    ip: String
  }
`);

const loggingMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('ip:', req.ip);
  next();
}

var root = {
  ip: function (args, request) {
    return request.ip;
  }
};

var app = express();
app.use(loggingMiddleware);
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: root,
  graphiql: true,
}));
app.listen(4000);
console.log('Running a GraphQL API server at localhost:4000/graphql');
```

result of
[GraphiQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxpFR.png)